# Trying to get the images to lay out in a grid on the page without affecting animation

Tags: html, css, image

got this problem where I want the images to lay out in a grid on the page but the animation I have seems to get affected with the things that I've tried. For instance the banner can get off center or get bigger than the image...

Here's a fiddle of what I've got so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/fnGwP/

So, I've finally got the images centered but the just line up in an ugly column that goes strait down.

I'd like at least two images on the top and two on the bottom with a space between each image. Any ideas?

Here's the html:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
                <div class="view view-first">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/399" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>Item 1</h2>
                        <br>
                        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Buy now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="view view-first">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/399" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>Item 1</h2>
                        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="view view-first">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/399" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>Item 1</h2>
                        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">more info</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="view view-first">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/399" />
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>Item 11</h2>
                        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">Have a look</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>       
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And some of the CSS:

```
#content {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 35px 0 35px 0;

}

#main {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*----------- grid ----------*/

.view {
   width: 399px;
   height: 266px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {
   width: 399px;
   height: 266px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

/*----------- photos ----------*/
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   width: 399px;
   height:auto;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** understand your question correct : add `text-align: center` to .`content`

```css
#content {
    ...
    text-align: center;
}
```

set float on `view-first` and `clear:right` to every second of them :

```css
div.view-first {
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
}
div.view-first:nth-child(2n+0) {
    clear: right;
}
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/59Hjc/** (updated, completely forgot a margin)

Comment: Thanks David, the #content {text-align: center;} worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT)

here i made a quick/simple changes

i've changed the class .view to this:

```
.view {
    width: 399px;
    height: 266px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

are you trying to get this?
http://jsfiddle.net/fnGwP/6/

Comment: ya! that's close but I would like some space between the horizontal images as well and have the images rest in the center of the page. It looks like they are still aligning to the left.

Comment: Thanks MCSI, I needed to add #content {text-align: center;} to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to get things looking like I wanted I changed the CSS to:

```
#content {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 35px 0 35px 0;
    text-align: center;

}

#main {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*----------- grid ----------*/

.view {
    clear:both;
    width: 324px;
    height: 216px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {
   width: 324px;
   height: 216px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Thanks to MCSI and davidkonrad